# How would I assign weights as user-defined variables in model builder for the Weighted Overlay tool?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, weighted-overlay, arcgis-custom-widget

So I'm trying to create a geoprocessing service to be uploaded for an ArcGIS Online Geoprocessing Widget and I'm running into a roadblock. I've created a model shown below, but not only is it not inputting in the table for weighted the weighted overlay, it does not accept any of the parameters that would be the user-defined weights on the application.
[image: Geoprocessing Weighted Overlay Model]

Under the Calculate Value tool, I have the following code to form the weighted overlay table:

```
def CalcWOTable(NoCar, wt1, Traffic, wt2, TravelTime, wt3): 

  remap_string = "(1 1;2 2;3 3;4 4;5 5;NODATA NODATA)"  
  scale_string = "1 9 1"  
  WO_Table1 = "'{}' {} 'VALUE' {}".format(NoCar, wt1, remap_string)  
  WO_Table2 = "'{}' {} 'VALUE' {}".format(Traffic, wt2, remap_string)  
  WO_Table3 = "'{}' {} 'VALUE' {}".format(TravelTime, wt3, remap_string)  

  WO_Table  = "({}; {}); {}".format(WO_Table1, WO_Table2, WO_Table3, scale_string)  
  
  return WO_Table
```

Which corresponds to the expression: `CalcWOTable('%nocar%','%wt1%','%Traffic%','%wt2%','%TravelTime%','%wt3%',)`

If I run the model from the panel inputting in values to the parameters, it gives me these errors:

> ERROR 000859: The required parameter Weighted overlay table is empty,
> or is not the type of Weighted Overlay Table.
>
> ERROR 000859: The required parameter Output raster is empty, or is
> not the type of Raster Dataset.

I was wondering how would I need to move forward to connect my three user-defined parameters for weights to the Weighted Overlay table to successfully run this model?